Software split into 3 rpm packages - now getting "file ... conflicts with file from package"
I have software that is packaged using rpm. Say the previous release was in an rpm named MyPkg-2.0.3-21.centos7.x86_64.rpm
Now the new release is split into three separate rpms: MyPkg-2.1.1-5.centos7.x86_64.rpm, MyPkg-DB-2.1.1-5.centos7.x86_64.rpm and MyPkg-UI-2.1.1-5.centos7.x86_64.rpm
The "MyPkg-DB" package can be installed alone. "MyPkg" can be installed alone. "MyPkg-UI needs "MyPkg".
Now when I try installing "MyPkg-DB", I get a bunch of messages like file /usr/local/mypkg/bin/dbinfo from install of MyPkg-DB-2.1.1-5.centos7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package zyWAF-2.0.3-21.centos7.x86_64.
In the spec file for "MyPkg-DB" I've tried adding Obsoletes: MyPkg <= 2.0.3 but still get the errors. It works fine if I install using --replacefiles but that's not workable for a number of reasons.
How do I make this work?
Thanks!
